# How to set imgs left, center, right on collapsing toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

on my app i have a collapsing toolbar with three icons;
 hamburger icon, app logo, setting icon,

My hamburger icon is on the left and the settings icon on the right and i'm trying to center the app logo in the toolbar. But it appear next to my settings logo instead that in the center. any ideas why am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/colappsingtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@color/lightBlack"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll|snap"
            app:title="">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp" >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="23dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:src="@drawable/ic_account" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/accoun_btn"
                android:layout_width="23dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code into my Android studio 3.5, as I am using androidx framework, but I don't think it would be any issue to solve it. Check my code from below :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/colappsingtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll|snap"
            app:title="">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp" >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                        android:src="@drawable/ic_beach_access_black_24dp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/accoun_btn"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/accoun_btn_1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="23dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Happy `coding`